# Reconstructing image with dominant frequencies

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

How would you take a Fourier transform of an image and reconstruct it with, say, only the 10 most dominant frequencies in Matlab? I couldn't see anything too useful in the Matlab help. Many thanks!

Comment: 1.-Take the fourier trasform. 2.-delete non-wanted frequencies. 3.-Take the inverse fourier transfor 4.-Profit. I have enormous doubts in you really looking into the help, as this is probably one of the most common problems in image processing. Look more, you probably will find tons of useful information! Suggested keyword: DCT. Good luck.

Comment: @AnderBiguri How do you delete unwanted frequencies though, or find the 10 most dominant frequencies in the first place? I realise it's a common problem, but I'm not very experienced with Matlab.

Comment: Try to read a bit of literature of what the Fourier transform *is*. Once you understand it, it is straightforward to know the dominant frequencies! Have a look at: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dct2.html

Comment: By "delete frequencies" @AnderBiguri meant set the values to zero. Finding the "10 most dominant frequencies" on the other hand is a tricky problem, eg, what width of the peak do you consider, what if two peaks are within this width, what about symmetric peaks, etc? I hope this helps but overall, as you've stated it, this question is too broad and ill defined for SO.

Comment: @AnderBiguri feel free the add that as an answer - it's worth accepting :)

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to keep the constant amplitude, i.e., preserve the mean of the image.

Sort all other frequencies by the absolute value of their amplitude, find the midpoint of the 10th and 11th highest amplitude and set all amplitudes with values below to zero, then transform back.

To experiment, one can consider that edges lead to the asymptotic behavior of amplitudes `abs(A(m,n))` of `C/(abs(m)+abs(n))`. Thus to preserve frequencies that might contribute to the definition of edges, sort by the modified absolute value `abs(A(m,n))*(1+abs(m)+abs(n))`. This will probably not make much of a difference for 10 preserved amplitudes, so experiment by taking O(N) or O(N*log(N)) frequencies for an NxN image.

Comment: All peaks will have a non-zero width, so, in practice, if you sort by amplitude your first 10 values will be the largest peak and a bunch of immediately neighboring points, not other peaks.